# Reindex Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas df. I wish to reindex the date column based on input for each name.

```
                 date  value1  value2 name
0  1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN    A
1  1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
2  1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5    A
3  1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    A
4  1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6     NaN    A
5  1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
6  1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
7  1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0    B
8  1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0    B
9  1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0    B
10 1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0    B
```

I wish to reindex the pandas df based on date column for each name.

This is what I am doing:

```
import datetime
s_date = datetime.datetime(1992, 8, 27, 7)
e_date =  datetime.datetime(1992, 8, 27, 12) 
df_time = pd.date_range(start=s_date, end=e_date,
                     freq='0.50H').to_frame(index=False, name='date')
df_time.date = pd.to_datetime(df_time.date)
df = pd.merge(df, df_time, on=['date'], how='outer')
```

My expected df is like:

```
                 date  value1  value2 name
1992-08-27 07:00:00    NaN      NaN    A
1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN    A
1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
1992-08-27 08:30:00    28.2    27.0    A
1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5    A
1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    A
1992-08-27 10:00:00    29.0     NaN    A
1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6     NaN    A
1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
1992-08-27 12:00:00    30.0    27.0    A
1992-08-27 07:00:00    NaN      NaN    B
1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN    B
1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0    B
1992-08-27 08:30:00    28.2    27.0    B
1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5    B
1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0    B
1992-08-27 10:00:00    29.6    37.0    B
1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0    B
1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0    B
1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    B
1992-08-27 12:00:00    30.0    27.0    B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you want to *resample* your timeseries, did I get that right? but in the expected output it seems sometimes you backward-fill (leaving NaN), sometimes you don't - what's the criterion?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to expose the missing values:

Create a dictionary containing the complete range of datetimes

```
new_dates = {"date" : lambda df: pd.date_range("1992-08-27 07:00:00", 
                                               "1992-08-27 12:00:00", 
                                               freq="30T")
               }
```

Pass the `new_dates` variable to [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) :

```
# pip install https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor
import pandas as pd


df.complete([new_dates], by = 'name')
 
   name                date  value1  value2
0     A 1992-08-27 07:00:00     NaN     NaN
1     A 1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN
2     A 1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0
3     A 1992-08-27 08:30:00     NaN     NaN
4     A 1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5
5     A 1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN
6     A 1992-08-27 10:00:00     NaN     NaN
7     A 1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6     NaN
8     A 1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0
9     A 1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0
10    A 1992-08-27 12:00:00     NaN     NaN
11    B 1992-08-27 07:00:00     NaN     NaN
12    B 1992-08-27 07:30:00     NaN     NaN
13    B 1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0
14    B 1992-08-27 08:30:00     NaN     NaN
15    B 1992-08-27 09:00:00     NaN     NaN
16    B 1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0
17    B 1992-08-27 10:00:00     NaN     NaN
18    B 1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0
19    B 1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0
20    B 1992-08-27 11:30:00     NaN     NaN
21    B 1992-08-27 12:00:00     NaN     NaN
```

[complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) is just an abstraction of Pandas functions to make processes like this easy (also helpful for duplicate index). You can ignore it and stick to Pandas only methods:

Create an index of the complete datetimes

```
new_index = pd.date_range("1992-08-27 07:00:00", 
                          "1992-08-27 12:00:00", 
                          freq="30T")

new_index = new_index.rename("date")
```

Run the groupby, and use `apply` to reindex each group.

```
(df
.set_index("date")
.groupby("name")
.apply (lambda df: df.reindex(new_index))
.drop(columns="name")
.reset_index()
 )

   name                date  value1  value2
0     A 1992-08-27 07:00:00     NaN     NaN
1     A 1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN
2     A 1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0
3     A 1992-08-27 08:30:00     NaN     NaN
4     A 1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5
5     A 1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN
6     A 1992-08-27 10:00:00     NaN     NaN
7     A 1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6     NaN
8     A 1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0
9     A 1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0
10    A 1992-08-27 12:00:00     NaN     NaN
11    B 1992-08-27 07:00:00     NaN     NaN
12    B 1992-08-27 07:30:00     NaN     NaN
13    B 1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0
14    B 1992-08-27 08:30:00     NaN     NaN
15    B 1992-08-27 09:00:00     NaN     NaN
16    B 1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0
17    B 1992-08-27 10:00:00     NaN     NaN
18    B 1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0
19    B 1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0
20    B 1992-08-27 11:30:00     NaN     NaN
21    B 1992-08-27 12:00:00     NaN     NaN
```

You can then `ffill` or `fillna`, depends on your criteria.

Comment: my bad. It should have a name. fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
# actuall dataframe
df
                  date  value1  value2 name
0  1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN    A
1  1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
2  1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5    A
3  1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    A
4  1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6     NaN    A
5  1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
6  1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
7  1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0    B
8  1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0    B
9  1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0    B
10 1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0    B

# create date range for multi-index
date_range = pd.date_range(start=datetime(1992, 8, 27, 7), 
                           end=datetime(1992, 8, 27, 12) , 
                           freq='30Min')
print(date_range)
DatetimeIndex(['1992-08-27 07:00:00', '1992-08-27 07:30:00',
               '1992-08-27 08:00:00', '1992-08-27 08:30:00',
               '1992-08-27 09:00:00', '1992-08-27 09:30:00',
               '1992-08-27 10:00:00', '1992-08-27 10:30:00',
               '1992-08-27 11:00:00', '1992-08-27 11:30:00',
               '1992-08-27 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='30T')

# multi-index for reindexing dataframe for all combination of name inside the daterange
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['name'].unique(), date_range])
multi_index
MultiIndex([('A', '1992-08-27 07:30:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 08:00:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 08:30:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 09:00:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 09:30:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 10:00:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 10:30:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 11:00:00'),
            ('A', '1992-08-27 11:30:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 07:30:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 08:00:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 08:30:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 09:00:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 09:30:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 10:00:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 10:30:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 11:00:00'),
            ('B', '1992-08-27 11:30:00')],
           )
 
result = df.set_index(['name', 'date']).reindex(multi_index).reset_index()
result = result[['level_1', 'value1', 'value2', 'level_0']]
result.columns = ['date', 'value1', 'value2', 'name']
print(result)
                  date  value1  value2 name
0  1992-08-27 07:00:00     NaN     NaN    A
1  1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0     NaN    A
2  1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
3  1992-08-27 08:30:00     NaN     NaN    A
4  1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5    A
5  1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0     NaN    A
6  1992-08-27 10:00:00     NaN     NaN    A
7  1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6     NaN    A
8  1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
9  1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
10 1992-08-27 12:00:00     NaN     NaN    A
11 1992-08-27 07:00:00     NaN     NaN    B
12 1992-08-27 07:30:00     NaN     NaN    B
13 1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0    B
14 1992-08-27 08:30:00     NaN     NaN    B
15 1992-08-27 09:00:00     NaN     NaN    B
16 1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0    B
17 1992-08-27 10:00:00     NaN     NaN    B
18 1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0    B
19 1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0    B
20 1992-08-27 11:30:00     NaN     NaN    B
21 1992-08-27 12:00:00     NaN     NaN    B
```

Comment: i think you are missing `07:00:00 `and `12:00:00` for your output